# Register Taxonomy how can display?

Tags: php, wordpress

**// taxonomy code:**

```
register_taxonomy( 'product_size', 'product', array(
    'labels'    =>  array( 
        'name'  => 'Size',
        'add_new'   => 'Add Product Size',
        'add_new_item'  => 'Add Product Size',
    ),
    'public'    =>  true,
    'hierarchical'  =>  true,
));
```

**// display code here:**

```
<li>
    <span>Sizes:</span>
    <?php  
        $sizes = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_size' );
        $names = array();
        foreach ($sizes as $size) :
        $names[]  = $size->name;           
        endforeach;
        echo implode( ', ', $name);
    ?>
</li>
```

But does not work, and displays the message:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\global\wp-content\themes\newcomet\inc\customoze\customoze-woocommerce.php on line 153

How can solve this? Please help me.

Comment: If the below code return "size variable is not an array!" you have a problem with `get_the_terms` function.
    ````<li>
        <span>Sizes:</span>
        <?php  
            $sizes = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_size' );
            $names = array();
    
            if ( is_array($size) ) {
                foreach ($sizes as $size) {
                     $names[]  = $size->name;           
                }
            } else {
                die("size variable is not an array!");
            }
    
            echo implode( ', ', $name);
        ?>
    </li>````

Comment: `get_the_term()` can return an array, false if there's no terms, or WP_Error. You need to see what you're getting back: `print_r($sizes); die()` and see what it returns.